# Android listing contacts sync sources

Tags: java, android

Does anyone knows how to get the contacts sync sources in android? like google source, facebook source or from the phone contacts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes.

Depending on what you mean by "sync source", though.

Individual raw contacts are synced by account name and account type. The "name" is the user's login name for a "type" such as Google or Facebook. The Phone contacts will be always be Google, even if the user *isn't* syncing them.

For more explanation, see

[Reference docs for Contacts Provider](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/ContactsContract.RawContacts.html)

and

[Contacts Provider guide](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/contacts-provider.html)

Comment: thanks, I mean how can I distinguish a phone contacts from google sync contacts or some other sources like yahoo, facebook, etc... Since when I try to use `cursor = cr.query(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI, null,null, null, null);` I always get all the contacts instead of just the phone contacts.